# How to create an animated tiled background from a texture atlas with Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, graphics, animation, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I want to create a CCLayer with an **animated tiled background** from a **larger texture atlas** with **Cocos2d**.

I know how to drop a background in a CCLayer. I know how to create an animated CCSprite. I even know how to handle tiled world maps. **But I can't find a proper way to combine all these elements in the desired form.**

**How would I do this?**

---

Example case: Let's say I have a 512x512 texture atlas. On it are six frames drawn next to each other, all of them 32x32, starting from the top left (0.0).

Now I would like my CCLayer's background to display a tiled image consisting of 10 by 15 tiles. Plus, the tiles themselves should animate with the six frames from the texture atlas.

As a bonus, the animation itself should be controllable. (I want to be able to speed it up, slow it down or reverse it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the sprite from the tile map

```
CCTMXLayer *layer = [map layerNamed:@"Layer"];
CCSprite *tile = [layer tileAt:ccp(x, y)];
```

and run a `CCAnimation` action on it.

Comment: Could you post an example of the CCAnimation code. I have not got this to work. Thanks